# Spring-rabbit use log4j2 AmqpAppender

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, spring-rabbit

**Versions of libraries**

soft version: spring-rabbit 1.7.1.RELEASE

log4j2 : 2.8.2

slf4j : 1.7.7

**log4j2 config**

```
<appenders>
    <console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{HH:mm:ss:SSS}] [%p] - %l - %m%n"/>
    </console>
    <!--<Kafka name="Kafka" topic="log-test">-->
        <!--<PatternLayout pattern="%date %message"/>-->
        <!--<Property name="bootstrap.servers">192.168.3.166:9090,192.168.3.166:9091,192.168.3.166:9092</Property>-->
    <!--</Kafka>-->
    <RabbitMQ name="rabbitmq_logdata_tojson"
              host="${sys:rabbitmq_host}"
              port="${sys:rabbitmq_port}"
              user="${sys:rabbitmq_user}"
              password="${sys:rabbitmq_password}"
              virtualHost="/"
              exchange="${sys:rabbitmq_exchange}"
              exchangeType="${sys:rabbitmq_exchangeType}"
              declareExchange="true"
              durable="true"
              autoDelete="false"
              applicationId="${sys:rabbitmq_qname_4logdata.json}"
              routingKeyPattern="${sys:rabbitmq_qname_4logdata.json}"
              contentType="text/plain"
              contentEncoding="${sys:log4j2_charset}"
              generateId="false"
              deliveryMode="NON_PERSISTENT"
              charset="${sys:log4j2_charset}"
              senderPoolSize="1" maxSenderRetries="5">
    </RabbitMQ>

    <!--flume appender的配置，此处采用Avro类型 -->
    <!--<Flume name="flume_logdata_in" compress="false" type="Avro" >-->
        <!--<Agent host="192.168.2.111" port="4444"/>-->
    <!--</Flume>-->

</appenders>

<loggers>

    <logger name="${sys:rabbitmq_qname_4logdata.json}" level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="rabbitmq_logdata_tojson"/>
    </logger>

    <!--<logger name="${sys:rabbitmq_qname_4logdata}" level="info">-->
        <!--<appender-ref ref="rabbitmq_logdata_tobyte"/>-->
    <!--</logger>-->

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
        <!--<appender-ref ref="Kafka"/>-->
    </root>
</loggers>
```

**Java code**

```
private static final Logger writeQueueLog= LoggerFactory.getLogger(System.getProperty("rabbitmq_qname_4logdata.json"));
writeQueueLog.info(jsonObject.toString());
```

**System.properties**

```
rabbitmq_qname_4logdata.json=user.behavior.countmessage.queue
rabbitmq_qname_4logdata=user.behavior.logdatainfo.queue
```

When I user AMQPAppender to send message to rabbitmq, always has some other logger message.

I had debug APQPAppender source code, when method "append" has been called, all of the events are right. But the Sender is running，always has some events from other logger, at last, the message count is right.

Then, I changed append queue to *String* like this : `private final LinkedBlockingQueue<String> eventsStrs = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();`, and add data in method *append()*,

I see all the values are right, but values from events have some wrong message.

I guess the event has been changed in other place.

I have no idea about it, can you help me?

Comment: check if another dependency (probably AMQP) is using log4j and exclude the dependency logger

Comment: i had see the dependency, there is no other dependency about amqp

Comment: I have found the issues, in log4j2 the class "ReusableLogEventFactory",method is "createEvent", in one thread , the event always use a single log event, i had commented the single code , the issues is solve. But I really don't know why it will use 
 this ReusableLogEventFactory? who can tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this code in Log4J2...

```
    if (LOG_EVENT_FACTORY == null) {
        LOG_EVENT_FACTORY = Constants.ENABLE_THREADLOCALS
                ? new ReusableLogEventFactory()
                : new DefaultLogEventFactory();
    }
```

If you run with `-Dlog4j2.enable.threadlocals=false` it will be thread-safe.

I will add an option to the Spring appender to send the message on the calling thread instead of handing off to another thread, which will make using the `ReusableLogEventFactory` safe.

You can also explicitly set the event factory with `Log4jLogEventFactory`.

See **System Properties** [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html).

Comment: thank you for you reply. I had fix it. before load log4j2.xml , I add a system property .